# Nested quotations in postgres SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql

I have the following (correct) SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE identification -> 'persons' @> 
'[{"id_person":"1234567890"}]'
```

It works from pgAdmin and returns correct result. In order to move it to my nodeJS code, I have to define a string variable (put in between quotations), something like:

```
var sql="...";
```

How should I do it, having in mind the nested quotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it by concatenating strings:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE identification -> 'persons' @> '"
      + '[{"id_person":"1234567890"}]'
      + "'";
```